# Get tracked effects when running callback

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Vue tracks reactive effects automatically when using `watchEffect` and `watch` and re-runs the callback whenever the effects change. Is there a way to "extract" the values of the effects being tracked? Something like this

```
const foo = ref(0)
const bar = ref(true)

someWatchEffectLikeMethod(
  () => console.log(foo.value, bar.value), // 0, true 
  (values) => console.log(...values) // 0, true
)
```

I thought possibly `effectScope` might offer some utility like this but it doesn't expose the effects being tracked. Is it possible to "extract" the reactive values from a callback when it is run?

Comment: It may be available in effectScope but it's not documented and you shouldn't rely on it. Just use watch() for anything that needs fine-grained control, that's clearly the case for it

Comment: Watch won’t tell me what the reactive values are inside a callback. I’d like to run a callback and then get an array of everything that is being tracked. Watch requires I know the reactive values ahead of time.

Comment: Generally you'd be able to explicitly list the inputs because you write the rest of code and know which inputs you use. You don't necessarily need to know them beforehand, a list can be dynamic. If you have a specific problem, consider updating the question with the details. Currently it looks like XY problem, as this can't be normally achieved with watchEffect afaik

Comment: I’d like to author a composition that accepts a callback. A callback that may contain reactive values. And then I have some logic I’d like to do based on the reactive values. Obviously I could have the user of the composition pass in an array of the reactive values. But since vue can already tract these values, it seems like I should be able to just ask vue what they are.

Comment: I see. Could be that way, but no, it's internal data. watch() is always used for such cases.